# Change specific settings with gsettings/dconf key. (archlinux, linux-lts-4.19)

Tags: scripting, dconf, gsettings

I am trying to change the "custom-command" value for the Tilix terminal emulator in dconf from `python3 $HOME/Scripts/memux/main.py` to `python3 $HOME/.pps/pecan.py`, but I can't figure out the format for use with the dconf command line tool, and gsettings seems to lack the functionality to change a single setting of a key. Using the GUI is not an option. I did rtfm, and the last argument needs to be a string in "GVariant format".

```
dconf write /com/gexperts/Tilix/profiles/2b7c4080-0ddd-46c5-8f23-563fd3ba789d/custom-command (some-argument)
```

Running the above command with no final argument results in the following.

```
error: value not specified

Usage:
  dconf write KEY VALUE 

Write a new value to a key

Arguments:
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)
```

How do I format the string so that dconf accepts it? Or, if there's another better way, how do I set the value via that? 
Below is a pair of screenshots with the GUI dconf-editor page containing the value I need to edit, if that helps.
[image: profiles, Tilix dconf]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just enclosing the whole command in quotes?

Comment: Well, no. I don't know the entire command to try that with. And wouldn't that essentially ask the shell to run "/usr/bin/(comand with arguments)"?

Comment: I mean something like "python script.py", it looks like from you screenshot that it is using the shell in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
dconf write /com/gexperts/Tilix/profiles/2b7c4080-0ddd-46c5-8f23-563fd3ba789d/custom-command "'python3 $HOME/.pps/pecan.py'"
```

Regarding the string in GVariant format, they're documented here:
https://docs.gtk.org/glib/gvariant-text.html